# Rails: Filter content using link_to (links) instead of checkbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to filter my content based on tags. I would rather use links instead of a checkbox form that filters content based on which tags are checked by the user. I currently generate links using the code below:

```
link_to tag.name, user_path(tags: tag.id)
```

This creates urls of the format `?tag=15`

This works to display all content with tag=15 but the user should be able to select multiple tags.

When a user clicks on a second filter link the new tag should be appended to the tag param and now content with both tags should be displayed. Basically, I would like to generate urls that look like:

```
?tag[]=15&tag[]=1
```

Is it even possible to specify the tags param as an array in link_to? If so, how can I append subsequent tags to the end of the url? Is there a better way to accomplish filtering through links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create the links like this:

```
link_to tag.name, user_path(tags: "#{params[:tags]},#{tag.id})
```

And then in the controller use

```
@tags = params[:tags].split(',')
```